# mulitple url hashtags not being read in properly

Tags: javascript, url

I have recently nabbed an example of reading in multiple hashtags from a url, while the first split works perfectly fine the second time I try to spilt the values a second time it seems not to be read in as seen I have tried to use the alerts to determine the problem and they stop working shot of the keyValuePair is initialized .

```
    var mangaNumber = 0;
    var chapterNumber = 0;

    var i, variables = window.location.hash.split(';');

    if (variables.length > 0) {
    // Variables present in hash
    for (i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {

        var keyValuePair = variables.split('=');

        if (keyValuePair[0] == mangaNo) {
            mangaNumber = unescape(keyValuePair[1]);
            alert(mangaNumber);
        }
        if (keyValuePair[0] == chapterNo) {
            chapterNumber = unescape(keyValuePair[1]);
            alert(chapterNumber);
        }
        if (keyValuePair[0] == pageNo) {
            pageNumber = unescape(keyValuePair[1]);
            alert(pageNumber);
        }
    }
}
else {
    // No variables in the hash
    alert('this is a fail foo');
}
```

Comment: I presume you are generating urls like this: http://example.com/index.php#foo=bar#foo2=bar2 if so wouldnt it make sense to split the URL at # and then drop the first array element and then you should be left with: foo=bar and foo2=bar2 then you can do the split at = to get your keys and values

Comment: shouldn't you split by `#` instead of `;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is just an error you made when you posted it here, but try this:

```
var keyValuePair = variables[i].split('=');
```

Also, unless `mangaNo` etc actually are variables (and not strings), you need to quote them:

```
if (keyValuePair[0] == "mangaNo") {
  mangaNumber = unescape(keyValuePair[1]);
  alert(mangaNumber);
}
...
if (keyValuePair[0] == "chapterNo") {
...
if (keyValuePair[0] == "pageNo") {
```